# Query retorna nada

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Estou a fazer uma aplicação em android com recurso a sqlite mas não estou a conseguir retornar nada com estes *where statments*.

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

> id dia mes valor1 valor2

e o seguinte cursor:

```
resultado = db.rawQuery(
       String.format("SELECT * FROM %s 
                      WHERE ((%s>=15 AND %s=%d-1) AND (%s<=14 AND %s=%d))", 
                      NomeTabela, Coluna2, Coluna3, mes, Coluna2, Coluna3, mes),null);
```

ou seja:

```
select * from NomeTabela where ((dia>=15 and mes=valor-1) and (dia<=14 and mes=valor))
```

estou a fazer algo errado?

Comment: Sem saber que valores existem na tabela e quais devem retornar, não poderemos dizer o que está errado.

Comment: Na realidade e tal como ramaral já mencionou, mostra-nos os dados da tabela, para que seja possivel compreender o que poderá estar a acontecer.

Answer (score 2):

O problema está na seu filtro de consulta:

```
where ((dia>=15 and mes=valor-1) and (dia<=14 and mes=valor))
```

Perceba que você colocou 2 condições conflitantes na clásula where: **mes=valor-1** e **mes=valor**. Mês nunca poderá assumir ambos os valores, por isso sua consulta nunca retornará resultados. Se você quiser que a query retorne resultados caso eles se encaixem na primeira condição parentizada OU na outra, a condição deverá ser:

```
where ((dia>=15 and mes=valor-1) or (dia<=14 and mes=valor))
```

Espero ter ajudado :)